# EditField issue in BlackBerry device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-editfield

I am using `EditField` in my application. The `EditField` is editable while using **virtual keyboard** but it requires long press to edit with **quetry** keypad. I tried all possible way which I can but didn't find what is causing the problem.

I am testing it in **Torch 9800**. Is there any clue about it please welcome.

```
//FOR NICKNAME SEARCH
        nicknameSearchHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
            protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
                setPositionChild(getField(0),0,10);
                layoutChild(getField(0),150,height+5);

                setPositionChild(
                        getField(1), Display.getWidth()/2+35, 
                        0);
                layoutChild(
                        getField(1), 
                        width+16, 
                        height);    

                setExtent(width, 50);
            }      
        };



        _nickname = new EditField("" ,_initialName){
            protected void onFocus(int direction) {
                super.onFocus(direction);   
                this.setText("");
                invalidate();
            }

        };
        //_nickname.setMargin(10,50,5,5);
        _nickname.setBorder(roundedBorder);

        _findByNickName = new ButtonField("  Search " ,ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        _findByNickName.setMargin(7,5,5,5);
        _findByNickName.setChangeListener(this);
        nicknameSearchHFM.setMargin(20,0,0,10);
        nicknameSearchHFM.add(_nickname);
        nicknameSearchHFM.add(_findByNickName);
```

Comment: will you post the code that you tried ?

Comment: @signare:here is my code.I am using one Editfield and a button in a HorizontalField manager.

Comment: why you using  protected void onFocus(int direction) {
                super.onFocus(direction);   
                this.setText("");
                invalidate();
            } ?

Comment: I am using some hint here. when focus will be there the hint will be replaced by blank String ("").

Comment: Same problem is also on another screen and there I am not using this method.Also, I have tried it without this method but no gain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27403/discussion-between-pawan-and-signare)